# Performance on finder methods to retrieve database data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to know what are advantages and disavantages (relating to performance) to use the `User.all` method and then perform finder methods on the result for each request needed instead of use `User.find(<id>)` to retrieve each record singly.

I ask this because in my *view* file I have something like this:

```
accounts.each { |account|
  puts account.user.name
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

*For example, how the Stackoverflow website would handle tags regarding finder methods?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't fetch `all` of anything unless you're sure the data set is very small, on the order of dozens of records at most. Fetching all users is a recipe for disaster as the memory usage of this operation will increase linearly with the number of users on your system.

You **must** use the `find` or `where` methods when retrieving sub-sets under most circumstances unless you can be absolutely sure that the number of records involved is trivial.

I would even advocate using `select_values` or `select_rows` when all you need is a tiny bit of data without the overhead of a model, something that works well for large tabular lists.

Remember when you load a model, you load *everything* associated with it by default. For users this could include their extended biography, their address, their favorite color, their email, their password, and all you use is their name before throwing that object away. Fetch only what you need if performance is a concern.

It is almost always a mistake to have the following in your controller:

```
@users = Users.all
```

What you need to do is paginate or that page will get progressively slower as more users sign up on your system. At some point the page will never render properly as it will time out first.

Comment: @tadman - 1.000 can be trivial? 10.000 can be trivial? 100.000 can be trivial? Just to know...

Comment: Trivial generally means "dozens", though for really light-weight records where they have only a few simple fields, you may be able to get away with hundreds. Heavier objects add up quickly.

Comment: @tadman - So, to use 1.000 'User.find(<id>)' methods in an 'each' block is a mistake?

Comment: @tadman - I also updated the question with a little "sub-question".

Comment: The idea when designing an efficient application is to try and make the minimum number of queries possible while fetching the minimum amount of information required. At some point it won't matter to optimize further, where for lightly loaded applications that aren't performance-conscious this can be very relaxed. 1,000 instances of `User.find` is a mistake. Instead you should be doing `User.where(:id => ids)` where `ids` is a list of IDs you want. Fetch in batches as big as you need since the time to create and execute a statement does add up if done repeatedly.